# Reading from Serial Port always times out

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I am writing software for a POS terminal. This terminal has a printer that is attached to a cash drawer. I need to send a code to the printer, and listen for what is returned to determine whether or not the cash drawer is open. Using MSComm, I had logic that worked in VB6, so I know the actual Hex code I am sending is correct.

This code always returns "Error: Serial Port read timed out". I do not know what I am doing wrong with the read portion. Please advise, how do I listen for what the port is sending back as a response?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ' Receive strings from a serial port. 
    Dim returnStr As String = ""
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim com3 As IO.Ports.SerialPort = Nothing

    logfile.WriteLine("STARTCASHDRAWERSTATUSCHECK")
    Try
        com3 = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM3")
        com3.WriteLine(ChrW(&H1B) & ChrW(&H75) & ChrW(&H0))
        com3.BaudRate = SetPortBaudRate(9600)
        com3.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
        com3.DataBits = SetPortDataBits(8)
        com3.StopBits = SetPortStopBits(1)
        com3.Handshake = IO.Ports.Handshake.RequestToSend
        com3.ReadTimeout = 10000
        Do
            x = x + 1
            Dim Incoming As String = com3.ReadLine()
            logfile.WriteLine(x & "incoming" & Incoming & "x")
            If Incoming Is Nothing Then
                logfile.WriteLine("Button2resultEXITDO" & x)
                Exit Do
            Else
                returnStr &= Incoming & vbCrLf
            End If
            If x > 10 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    Catch ex As TimeoutException
        returnStr = "Error: Serial Port read timed out."
    Finally
        If com3 IsNot Nothing Then com3.Close()
    End Try

    logfile.WriteLine("Button2result:" & returnStr)
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You *must* configure the serial port correctly.  Baudrate, Parity, DataBits and StopBits.  And Handshake, super important.  Start with Handshake.RequestToSend.  Try this first with a program like Putty or HyperTerminal so you can be sure that the basic wiring is okay.

Comment: Please further explain, how to I code this Handshake.requesttosend? I edited my code above to what I thought needed to be added. Please advise further. Thanks!

Comment: You need your port configuration to occur before you start writing/reading to the port.

Comment: `com3.PortName = "COM3"` should replace the first line after the Try. After the ReadTimeout property line, then `com3.Open` and `com3.WriteLine` would occur.